# Howto enable SASL authentication with OpenLDAP - missing nsContainer objectClass

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, config, openldap, rhel7

I am using OpenLDAP, tried on RHEL7 and Ubuntu

```
# slapd -V
@(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd 2.4.44 (Apr  3 2018 08:03:36) $
    mockbuild@x86-034.build.eng.bos.redhat.com:/builddir/build/BUILD/openldap-2.4.44/openldap-2.4.44/servers/slapd

# uname -a
Linux xxx-yyy-ldap2 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 19 11:24:13 EDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

or

```
ldap# uname -a
Linux xxx-ldap2 4.4.0-131-generic #157-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 12 15:51:36 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@xxx-ldap2:/etc/ldap# 
# slapd -V
@(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd  (Ubuntu) (May 22 2018 13:54:12) $
    buildd@lcy01-amd64-019:/build/openldap-t_Ta0O/openldap-2.4.42+dfsg/debian/build/servers/slapd
```

When I try to add SASL mapping on a running server by following the [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Directory_Server/8.2/html/Administration_Guide/SASL.html), I fail with:

```
    ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/openldap/changes-sasl-mapping.ldif
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
adding new entry "cn=sasl,cn=config"
ldap_add: Invalid syntax (21)
    additional info: objectClass: value #1 invalid per syntax
```

Where `changes-sasl-mapping.ldif` contains:

```
#root sasl configuration
dn: cn=sasl,cn=config
objectClass: top
objectClass: nsContainer
cn: sasl

#sasl mapping container 
dn: cn=mapping,cn=sasl,cn=config
objectClass: top
objectClass: nsContainer
cn: mapping

#sasl mapping node
dn: cn=testmap,cn=mapping,cn=sasl,cn=config
objectclass: top
objectclass: nsSaslMapping
cn: testmap
nsSaslMapRegexString: \(.*\)@\(.*\)\.\(.*\)
nsSaslMapFilterTemplate: (objectclass=inetOrgPerson)
nsSaslMapBaseDNTemplate: uid=\1,ou=Users,dc=\2,dc=\3
```

I assume the issue is by schema unsupported/undefined attribute or objectclass `nsContainer`.

I searched for it in `/etc/openldap/schema/.` and in `/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn\=config/cn\=schema/`. In both cases

```
grep -rn . -e 'nsContainer'
```

gave me nothing. No hit. I expect that `nsContainer` is defined somewhere. Since SASL should be supported by the OpenLDAP core I was not searching for plugins.

Anyway. I am lost lost and needing help.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you're trying to apply vendor-specific SASL config data for another LDAP server to OpenLDAP's dynamic configuration. This will definitely not work no matter what.

You have to use OpenLDAP's configuration options like described in [OpenLDAP 2.4 Admin Guide](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/sasl.html#Mapping%20Authentication%20Identities).

Unfortunately the docs still describe the static configuration method. If you're using dynamic config method (aka *cn=config*) you would have to consult the man-page of the config backend for details about attribute *olcAuthzRegexp*.

See: [slapd-config(5)](https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapd-config)